# How to use restws or services module in drupal to expose web services

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, content-management-system

Basically I need to post an article(Node) from a web application to drupal 7 application using web service. I found that restws (https://drupal.org/project/restws) and services (https://drupal.org/project/services) modules works for my requirement. But when I tried running these modules I'm getting 404 error, I referred to different tutorials and couldn't solve the problem. Kindly suggest me some useful resources to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to enable clean URLs in http server's configuration file(httpd.conf).

Procedure:

just uncomment the following line in httpd.conf to enable clean URLs

#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

Reference: http://www.learnbycode.com/content/how-enable-clean-urls-drupal-wamp-server

For Ubuntu System read at this link : Clean URLs for Ubuntu https://drupal.org/node/945860